# import neural network in simulink user defined matlab function

Tags: matlab, simulink

I am working on neural network project in Simulink. I have trained the neural network in matlab script file and saved the trained data into a .mat file. Now, I have to use this trained data in simulink user defined function where I can utilize this trained data for prediction. I have tried my many ways to load this data into the function but not able to get success.

I tried to load the mat file by load function and get_param function but these are not supported.

I have imported this trained data into workspace using model explorer and model workspace but still unable to get data from this workspace. I wish, I can use this imported workspace trained data into my user defined matlab function in Simulink.
I tried to use from workspace block but I think from workspace loads time series data and arrays or may be I am not sure how to used from workspace to load this neural net.

The code for training data and saving into file

```
net=feedforwardnet([10,5]); 
%set other parameters
net=train(net,[theta1;theta1D;theta1DD;theta2;theta2D;theta2DD],[tau1;tau2]);
save trainednet.mat net;
%theta and tau are the function variables
```

after this the variable neural network net is imported in workspace.
Now I want to used this net in user defined function given

```
 pridicted=sim(net,[theta1;theta1D;theta1DD;theta2;theta2D;theta2DD]);
```

Please ask, if any other information is missing. I guess, I could use from worskspace in some different way by saving the file in some different way. But I could not get it well.
Using Matlab R2012a

Answer (score 1):

I was not able to get data from workspace but Function 'load' is supported for code generation when using coder.extrinsic('load') to bypass code generation. Therefore adding these lines solved the problem

```
coder.extrinsic('load');
net=load('trainednet.mat');
```

Answer (score 0):

This may help https://www.mathworks.com/help/deeplearning/ref/network.gensim.html. It uses the gensim option wich transform the .net in matlab into a ann in simulink.

Comment: Please quote/explain the article, in case the link becomes broken.